# How do I determine if a message is deleted from telegram group chat in api results?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I am creating a telegram bot to fetch messages from a chat group. But I have noticed that inappropriate comments that are deleted by admin/me in the group are still fetched when I call /getUpdates method (i.e. using telegram api)

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot<token>/getUpdates
```

My question is - is there a way, I can tell that a message has been deleted in the group from the json results that I get when I call the /getUpdates endpoint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to look at `edited_message`, see: https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#update